# OpenLdap with Back-SQL : How to add mail attribute

Tags: sql, postgresql, openldap

I have installed openldap using the back-SQL with Postgres SQL.

I'm able to modify users, update attributes created by the initial SQL scripts, so far so good.

Now, I would like to add new attributes (like `mail`, `Description`). I have done several tests but I'm unable to understand how to perform this. I tried to add `mail` in mapping, ni persons ... both, but mail is never displayed.

Any suggestions? Documentation someone can point me to ?

Thanks

---

To answer to one questions, here are the SQL scripts for ref
[Sources for SQL scripts](https://git.openldap.org/openldap/openldap/-/tree/OPENLDAP_REL_ENG_2_5/servers/slapd/back-sql/rdbms_depend/pgsql)

---

yes, I have installed the SQL backend for openldap following these steps ( Postgres ): [link] [https://www.darold.net/projects/ldap_pg/HOWTO/x37.html#AEN45](https://git.openldap.org/openldap/openldap/-/tree/OPENLDAP_REL_ENG_2_5/servers/slapd/back-sql/rdbms_depend/pgsql)
When I try now to add a mobile with the mobile attribute , I get the following error :
[image]

but my config already have this schema ( InetOrgPerson ) :
[image]

This is my ldif file :[image]

I don't undestand the problem

Comment: What is "the back-SQL"?

Comment: "_created by the initial SQL scripts_", are you referring to [these scripts](https://github.com/openldap/openldap/blob/master/servers/slapd/back-sql/rdbms_depend/pgsql/) ? If not, which scripts are you talking about ? Update your post and make it clear. "_I tried to add mail in mapping, ni persons_", what did you try exactly ? "_mail is never displayed_", where ? Be clear so you can get some help. @jjanes "back-sql" refers to "sql backend for openldap".

Comment: Hi, so ye s, I'm referring to SQL backend for openldap. I have installed the backend and configured it with unixODBC and a postgress Database ( see reference here https://www.darold.net/projects/ldap_pg/HOWTO/x37.html#AEN45)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add more information, rather than posting answers that do not answer the question.

Comment: Look into the script testdb_metadata.sql, there is no mapping defined for mail, description and mobile attributes (see table ldap_attr_mappings). Just edit the script so that it suits your needs. Nb. the existing mapping for 'description' concerns the 'document' objectclass (table 'documents'), not inetOrgPerson (table 'persons').